# Reading many files in parallel in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to run a Python script on data of total size 3 Tb to calculate very simple statistics. The data is structured in 3000 directories, each directory contains a compressed file with size 1Gb (".trr" format).

For loading the data I use a library implemented in C (called mdanalysis). I am running the analysis on a node with 64 CPU cores and 250 Gb memory. I have used Joblib to loop over the directories in parallel and I was expecting to process 64 files in parallel, as this would be still fine with memory.

But When I execute and monitor CPU usage via htop I only see 10 CPU cores filled to barely 50%, which shows that my script is a disaster. Could you suggest any reason why the script is not being executed as it should be ? Apart from limited memory (which is not the case here) I do not see why the CPUs are not being used.  Via htop I can see that most of the processes are in state D.

Update : I have profiled my code using cProfile, and I can see that most of the time is spent in {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}. This confuses me as I have executed independent processes, and in my understanding this sould not involve thread locks slowing down the code. Does the thread lock show up  because I am reading files ? Is this a hint for I/O limitation ?

I am working on a minimal reproducible example (not so easy because of required data).

Comment: What's the issue? 50% is better than all cpu maxed at 100% as long as it works as expected

Comment: It is much slower than expected, the processes are not being executed in parallel.

Comment: Are you able to share your code and how you start the processes as a [mcve]? Perhaps you should try multiprocessing module or Dask / Pyspark rather than joblib? But also, Python won't be as fast as C/C++, Go, or Rust for example. Also, maybe you should distribute your dataset to multiple disks? Or load into a database that is actually meant to do analytics? I assume 3TB is plaintext file, not a specific binary format (what is trr file)?

Comment: If 64 developers share a same machine to write an application, they will not be much faster than 1 developer. This is the same thing with cores. Using 64 cores is useless if the task is disk-bound (or even memory bound). "3000 directories" is a lot and there is a good chance for the OS or the disk to be the bottleneck. In this cases cores will stall, waiting for the disk to be ready. Did you **profile** your script to check what is the bottleneck? Did you check the disk is not saturated?

Comment: I think the most likely reason is that the task is disk-bound, as mentioned by Jerome. I am familiarizing with profiling libraries to verify this. If you could suggest an easy way to verify this, please let me know.

Comment: Update : I have profiled my code using cProfile, and I can see that most of the time is spent in {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}. This confuses me as I have executed independent processes, and in my understanding this sould not involve thread locks slowing down the code. Does the thread lock show up  because I am reading files ? Is this a hint for I/O limitation ?

Comment: Is it possible that's the Python GIL?

Comment: A callstack should help you to know which function does the lock. AFAIK the GIL should not be an issue with multiprocessing (unless maybe if you do some communications between processes using manager objects or similar things). Some OS lock files when they are read/written, but I do not expect user functions to do that using basic user locks. I/O bound operation should rather wait on IO functions like fread/fwrite or dirent ones, or even the specific one of the OS (On Windows there are sync functions like WaitForSingleObject for example and Win32 functions for files).

Comment: You can use a simple IO top tool to check quickly if your hardware is saturated. However, not seeing the hardware saturated does not mean the processes are not bound by it (unfortunately). Processes can be bound by the latency of the operations on some SSDs for example (quite rare for many processes though). The OS stack can also be a limitation. On Windows there is the task manager and the pre-installed performance monitoring tool and linux has many IO top command-line tools for this. For an advanced analysis a deep profiling analysis is certainly required (using a good profiler).